# Slplit IPv4 address to minimum and maximum range

Tags: lua

Using Lua how do I split a given IP address to get the minimum and maximum range for example:

```
94.19.21.119
```

I have a csv like this:

```
18087936,18153471,"AU"
18153472,18219007,"JP"
18219008,18350079,"IN"
18350080,18874367,"CN"
```

thats read to 3 tables and the csv is min,max,country code:

```
IPfrom = {}
IPto = {}
IPCountry = {}
```

they get populated like this:

```
IPfrom[18087936] = L
IPto[L] = 18153471
IPCountry[L] = "AU"
```

with L being the line number of the io.read, what Im then trying to do is get the minimum range so I can without looping check if it exists then if it does that key holds the index of the maximum range and if the ip is within the min/max I get the country code. Probably a different way of doing things but the tables are over 100000 entries so looping is taking some time.

Comment: What is your definition of minimum and maximum range?  Do you have an associated net mask with this IP address as well?

Comment: Hi there, what I'm trying to do is get the 'minimum' and 'maximum' to then cross reference with a csv to get the country code, the csv is like this: "16777216","17367039","US"

Comment: @Col_Blimp The example in your comment doesn't look relevant to the example in your question. Edit your question to add an example with input and what expected to get.

Comment: @Col_Blimp:  Are the `IPfrom` keys at regular intervals?  If they are, it would make the lookup faster.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like the following will work for you:

```
--
-- Converts an IPv4 address into its integer value
--
function iptoint(ip)
    local ipint = 0
    local iter = string.gmatch(ip, "%d+")
    for i = 3, 0, -1 do
        local piece = tonumber(iter())
        if piece == nil or piece < 0 or piece > 255 then
            return nil
        end
        ipint = bit32.bor(ipint, bit32.lshift(piece, 8 * i))
    end
    return ipint
end

--
-- Looks up an IPv4 address in a multidimensional table, with the entries:
-- {start_address, end_address, country}
-- and returns the matching country
--
function iptocountry(ip, tbl)
    local ipint = iptoint(ip)
    if ipint == nil then
        return nil
    end
    for _,v in pairs(tbl) do
        if ipint >= v[1] and ipint <= v[2] then
            return v[3]
        end
    end
    return nil
end
```

Example usage:

```
local countries = {
    {16777216, 17367039, "US"},
    {1578300000, 1678300000, "CAN"}
    -- ... rest of entries loaded from CSV file
}

local ip = "94.19.21.119"
print (iptocountry(ip, countries)) -- prints CAN
```

Answer (score 1):

A hash table (the basic type in Lua) will give you O(N). An array (a table with no holes with indices from someMinAddr to someMaxAddr) will give you O(1), but use a significant amount of memory. A binary search through a properly sorted structured table could give you O(log N), which for 100000 addresses is probably worth the effort. I imagine you could have a structure like this:

```
IPfrom = {
    {line=L1, addFrom=from1, addrTo=to1, c=country1}, 
    {line=L2, addFrom=from2, addrTo=to2, c=country2}, 
    {line=L3, addFrom=from3, addrTo=to3, c=country3}, 
    {line=L4, addFrom=from4, addrTo=to4, c=country4}, 
    ...
}
```

because I don't see the point of separating the to and country fields from the other info, just means more table lookup. Anyways if you really do want to separate them the following is not affected:

```
-- init: 
create table from CSV file
sort IPFrom on addFrom field

-- as many times as required: 
function findIP(addr)
    is addr smaller than IPfrom[middle].addrTo3?
    if yes, is addr smaller than IPfrom[middle of middle]?
        etc
end
```

This is recursive so if you structure it properly you can use tail calls and not worry about stack overflow (;), something like

```
function findIPRecurs(addr, ipTbl, indxMin, indxMax)
    local middle = (indxMin + indxMax )/2
    local midAddr = ipTbl[middle].addrFrom
    if addr < midAddr then
        return findIPRecurs(addr, ipTbl, indxMin, middle)
    else if addr > midAddr then
        return findIPRecurs(addr, ipTbl, middle, indxMax)
    else -- have entry:
        return middle
    end
end

function findIP(addr)
    return findIPRecurs(addr, ipTbl, 1, #ipTbl)
end
```

I have not tested this so there might be some fixing up to do but you get the idea. This will use the same memory as O(N) method but for large arrays will be considerably faster; much less memory than O(1) method, and probably acceptably slower.